# RNCAndroidDropdownPicker was not found in the UIManager

Tags: react-native, native-base

I have installed nativebase version 2.15.2. I am getting following error in android:

```
requireNativeComponent "RNCAndroidDropdownPicker" was not found in the UIManager
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's working for me:

```
npm install @react-native-picker/picker --save
```

**Linking:**

**iOS:**

```
cd ios && pod install
```

**Android:**

```
Clear and gradle run
```

Answer (score 7):

I started getting this issue after installing the node modules on fresh install. After some research I resolved it by installing the package.

If you are using `yarn` for package installing

```
yarn add @react-native-community/picker
```

If you are using npm

```
npm install @react-native-community/picker
```

If you are using expo

```
expo install @react-native-community/picker
```

Comment: @react-native-community/picker was deprecated but it should work the same with @react-native-picker/picker

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with native-base version 2.x
Replace this:

```
import { Picker, Button, Container, Form, Item, Card, Text, Icon, Label } from 'native-base';
```

for this:

```
import { Picker } from '@react-native-picker/picker';
import { Button, Container, Form, Item, Card, Text, Icon, Label } from 'native-base';
```

Of course you need to install:

@react-native-picker/picker

```
yarn add @react-native-picker/picker
```

Tested in react-native >= 0.68.x

Answer (score 0):

Just had the same issue with a fresh install (no expo) Simple fix for me was the usual suspects.

Reset the server & cache

`npx react-native start --reset-cache`

Remove node modules, clean, and build. Reinstall and run again.

`rm -rf node_modules`

`npm i`

`cd android/`

`./gradlew clean`

`cd ../`

`npx react-native run-android`

Comment: I have created new project and getting this issue. I have comment picker from nativebase and using from third party

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue when I was working with AWS amplify. I was able to resolve it by simply installing picker package.

```
npm install @react-native-community/picker
```